# Iterating through file read

Tags: python, python-3.x

*Using Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit) on Windows 10.*

I have a file called upgrade.csv that contains this:

```
['$APPL','$FB','$MSLI','$AMZN','$NVDA','$WMT','$NFLX']
```

I'd like to loop through each of these stock symbols.

Pulling from the file with the following code returns:

```
[
'
$
A
P
P
L
'
,
'
$
F
B
'
,
```

And so on through the data.

1st code:

```
file = open('upgrades.csv', 'r')
upgrades = (file.read())
file.close()
upgrades = list(upgrades)
for i in range(len(upgrades)):
    print(upgrades[i])
```

Pulling from an explicit string returns what I want:

```
$APPL
$FB
$MSLI
$AMZN
$NVDA
$WMT
$NFLX
```

2nd code:

```
upgrades = ['$APPL','$FB','$MSLI','$AMZN','$NVDA','$WMT','$NFLX']
upgrades = list(upgrades)
for i in range(len(upgrades)):
    print(upgrades[i])
```

Please help me pull data from the file and get this result:

```
$APPL
$FB
$MSLI
$AMZN
$NVDA
$WMT
$NFLX
```

I've tried converting the data like:

```
upgrades = list(upgrades)
upgrades = str(upgrades)
upgrades = tuple(upgrades)
```

I also tried changing the file from csv to txt.

Comment: Try  googling readLine method. This method can be used for reading a file line by line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

treat it as a single line csv and proceed as follows.

```
with open('upgrades.csv', 'r') as upgrade:
    for line in upgrade.readlines():
        lines = line.split(",")
        for m in lines:print m
```

Comment: Thank you ... more thanks than I can say. I will accept this answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

```
In[5]: import json
  ...: 
  ...: with open('upgrades.csv', 'r') as f:
  ...:     data = json.loads(f.read().replace("'", '"'))
  ...: 
  ...: print(data)
  ...: for item in data:
  ...:     print(item)
  ...: 
['$APPL', '$FB', '$MSLI', '$AMZN', '$NVDA', '$WMT', '$NFLX']
$APPL
$FB
$MSLI
$AMZN
$NVDA
$WMT
$NFLX

In[6]: from ast import literal_eval
  ...: 
  ...: with open('upgrades.csv', 'r') as f:
  ...:     data = literal_eval(f.read())
  ...: 
  ...: print(data)
  ...: for item in data:
  ...:     print(item)
  ...: 
['$APPL', '$FB', '$MSLI', '$AMZN', '$NVDA', '$WMT', '$NFLX']
$APPL
$FB
$MSLI
$AMZN
$NVDA
$WMT
$NFLX
```

Comment: This is great. In the other answer, which I've already coded into the script, requires me to edit the file text to remove the brackets and apostrophes. I also didn't realize we could have the output show the input as you did in these examples. Very useful, thanks.

Comment: @MicahMorris No problem, just wanted to show another way. One issue with using `json.loads` is that having single quotes is *not* valid JSON, so I used `str.replace` to convert the single to double quotes. If one of the items had a single quote inside of it, `'$it\'s'`, this method would simply change that to a double quote (which might not be what you wanted). That is why I used `ast.literal_eval` in the second example, since it already looked like a Python list and `ast.literal_eval` is a safer way to convert it than using `eval`.